# Why isnt Brake and Accelerate declared in scope?

Tags: c++

Hey guys so I was assigned to debug and fix a given code. This assignment is supposed to work as such after we fix it:
**Demonstrate the class in a program that creates a Car object, and then calls the accelerate
function five times. After each call to the accelerate function, get the current speed of the
car and display it. Then, call the brake function six times. After each call to the brake
function, get the current speed of the car and display it**

Here is what I have - The problem is once it runs I get an error saying "Accelerate" and "Brake are not declared in scope this scope" which is weird since they are functions supposedly put in the right spots. Let me know if I missed anything thanks!!!

```
#include <math.h>

#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>

#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
class Car
{
private:
   int YearModel;
   int Speed;
   string Make;
public:
   Car(int, string, int);
   string getMake();
   int getModel();
   int getSpeed();
   int Accelerate(int aSpd);
   int Brake(int bSpd);
   void displayMenu();
};
Car::Car(int YearofModel, string Makeby, int Spd)
{
   YearModel = YearofModel;
   Make = Makeby;
   Speed = Spd;
}
string Car::getMake()
{
   return Make;
}
//To get the year of the car.
int Car::getModel()
{
   return YearModel;
}
//To holds the car actual speed.
int Car::getSpeed()
{
   return Speed;
} 
//To increase speed by 5.
int Car::Accelerate(int aSpd)
{
   aSpd = Speed;
   Speed = Speed + 5;
   return aSpd;
}
//To drop the speed of the car by 5.
int Car::Brake(int bSpd)
{
   bSpd = Speed;
   Speed = Speed - 5;
   return bSpd;
}
void displayMenu()
{
   cout << "\n Menu\n";
   cout << "----------------------------\n";
   cout << "A)Accelerate the Car\n";
   cout << "B)Push the Brake on the Car\n";
   cout << "C)Exit the program\n\n";
   cout << "Enter your choice: ";
}
int main()
{
   int Speed = 0; //Start Cars speed at zero.
   char choice; //Menu selection
   int year;
   string carModel;
   cout << "Enter car year: ";
   cin >> year;
   cout << "Enter the car model(without spaces): ";
   cin >> carModel;


   Car first(year, carModel, Speed);

   //Display the menu and get a valid selection
   do
   {
       displayMenu();
       cin >> choice;
       while (toupper(choice) < 'A' || toupper(choice) > 'C')
       {
           cout << "Please make a choice of A or B or C:";
           cin >> choice;
       }
       //Process the user's menu selection


       switch (choice)
       {
       case 'a':
       case 'A': cout << "You are accelerating the car. ";
       cout << Accelerate(first) << endl;
       break;
       case 'b':
       case 'B': cout << "You have choosen to push the brake.";
           cout << Brake(first) << endl;
           break;
       }
   }while (toupper(choice) != 'C');


   return 0;
   system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
first.Accelerate(speed)
```

---

This is the declaration of `Accelerate`:

```
int Car::Accelerate(int aSpd)
```

It's a method of `Car` that takes an `int` as an argument.

But what you're doing is:

```
Accelerate(first)
```

Which is a function call (to a function called `Accelerate` which is undeclared), and you're passing it a `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

As `Accelerate` and `Break` are functions of a `Car`, they must be called on a `Car` object: `first.Accelerate(42)`.

When you are using `Accelerate` and `Break` in the `main` function, they are called as free functions, which do not exists.

---

In your case it doesn't matter what values you pass to `Acceleate` and `Break`, as the arguments are overwritten and never used:

```
int Car::Accelerate(int aSpd)
{
   aSpd = Speed;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh ok sweet that fixed that. But now when I run the program, it just says for me to type the model and make(which is weird ) and then it displays 3 and 0 then says press any key and then is done...Shouldnt it be displaying the menu and whether or not I want to accelerate or break?

Comment: I say its weird because in the int main I had it so I put enter car year then model. Not at the same time...

Comment: So should it be written like that?
Car first= new Car(year, carModel, Speed);

if so it says that conversion from Car*to non scalar type car requested error\

Comment: @kurakura88 That wouldn't compile! You define a object but assign a pointer. Sure, you are thinking C++ and not Java?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking C# would look similar to C++, but I was wrong. Please disregard what I said.

Comment: Ok well so anyway it seems its just asking for year and make and then thats it...But there is so much more going on with the code lol!